# Does an actor or channel need to be managed (closed/terminated) when encapsulated by another object like TextWatcher?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I would like to implement a DebounceTextWatcher. I intend to use an `actor` to consume text changes and debounce on a specified time interval and subsequently forward events to an external consumer. The code would look as follows:

```
class DebounceTextWatcher(
  delayMs: Long = DebounceTextWatcher.DEFAULT_TIMER_DELAY_MS,
  handler: (text: String) -> Unit
) : TextWatcher {

  private val channel = GlobalScope.actor<String> {
    debounce(delayMs).consumeEach(handler)
  }

  override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    channel.offer(s?.toString().orEmpty())
  }

  override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
  override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

  companion object {
    const val DEFAULT_TIMER_DELAY_MS = 600L
  }
}

fun <T> ReceiveChannel<T>.debounce(timeMs: Long): ReceiveChannel<T> = GlobalScope.produce {
  var value = receive()

  whileSelect {
    onTimeout(timeMs) {
      send(value)
      value = receive()
      true
    }
    onReceive {
      value = it
      true
    }
  }
}
```

My concerns are

1. Is this the correct use of `GlobalScope` or should I pass in a `CoroutineContext` or `CoroutineScope` as a dependency?
2. Do I have to concern myself with invoking `close()` or terminating the `actor` in any way when the lifecycle of the `Activity`/`Fragment` holding the TextWatcher reference ends?

My assumption is that I do not have to concern myself with this based on [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/closing-coroutine-channels/2549) post but I wanted to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

The channel itself won't retain any resources, but your handler probably will. You risk this sequence of events:

1. an item lands in the channel's input queue
2. the application gets paused, its activity gets destroyed
3. the application resumes and now the item gets processed
4. your handler, bound to the old activity, runs and crashes the app

I got many spurious crashes in similar scenarios. I kept plugging one hole after another, and the app still kept crashing on some devices and in some special circumstances. It stopped only when I implemented the "master job" pattern. Later on Kotlin enforced this pattern.

Comment: what is the"master job" pattern?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy).